# How to destinguish or collate File objects from multiple file inputs

Tags: javascript, dom

Suppose I have a form with some slots for uploading files

```html
<input type="file" name="f2">
<input type="file" name="f2">
```

The user may select two files with the same name `foo` from different local directories, or may select the same file twice. Two different files may also share lastModified, size, and type. How can I identify if two files are the same or not, without having to load them and compare the content?

The information available is this

```json
{
    "lastModified": 1689015384038,
    "​​​name": "foo",
    "​​​size": 1058,
​​​    "type": "some_type",
    "​​​webkitRelativePath": ""
}
```

none of which is guaranteed to be unique. While a solution is to simply treat each input as "unique" (add a sequential number to the filename), it would save bandwith if the script could understand that two files are the same.

Or put it like this: If there were an UUID or some kind of hash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you are pointing out yourself you can only compare the properties of the file, like the name, type and size. This comparison is not perfect, but could work in practice.

In the following example I compare the size and the type for all the files added to the form.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  if (e.target.type == 'file') {
    form[`${e.target.name}_list`].value =
      [...e.target.files].map(file => file.name).join(',');
  }
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let files = [...form.file1.files].concat([...form.file2.files]);
  let identicalFiles = [];
  files.forEach((file1, i) => {
    files.filter((file, j) => j > i).forEach(file2 => {
      if (file1.size == file2.size && file1.type == file2.type) {
        identicalFiles.push([file1, file2]);
      }
    });
  });
  if (identicalFiles.length > 0) {
    console.log("the following files could be the same:", identicalFiles.map(arr => arr[0].name + ' = ' + arr[1].name).join(','));
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>
    <input type="file" name="file1" multiple/>
    <output name="file1_list"></output>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="file" name="file2" multiple/>
    <output name="file2_list"></output>
  </label>
  <label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </label>
</form>
```